Where do I find the construct_runtime macro?
I'm trying to do the tutorial Authorize specific nodes, however I'm not sure where to find the construct_runtime macro in my lib.rs file. The tutorial requires the line NodeAuthorization: pallet_node_authorization::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event<T>, Config<T>}, to be added (4th step in the Implement the Config trait section).
I tried adding the code:
construct_runtime!(
pub enum Runtime where
   Block = Block,
   NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
   UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic
 {
   /*** Add This Line ***/
   NodeAuthorization: pallet_node_authorization::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event<T>, Config<T>},
 }
);

directly in my lib.rs file, but this is obviously not the proper way of doing it...
Can somebody elaborate a bit more about what should be done exactly, please?
Edit: After some more investigation I realized that with the new version of the substrate-node-template, the format has changed for the runtime_construct. Here you can see the change substrate-node-template history in runtime/src/lib.rs line 278. However, I still need help on how to adapt the format to this new version.

Basically, the above answer is correct. Just make sure you use the same version of pallet-node-authorization with the "substrate-node-template" itself. In my case, I use the all modules as "git = "https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk.git", tag = "polkadot-v1.9.0"". It seems that parity tech merge all tools into the polkadot-sdk repo.
I think you can do as following:

add the following into Cargo.toml in runtime


pallet-node-authorization = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk.git", tag = "polkadot-v1.9.0", default-features = false }


follow the steps in tutorial until the "construct_runtime!" edit part

edit as the following in the lib.rs in runtime



#[frame_support::runtime]
mod runtime {
/*** add this line***/
#[runtime::pallet_index(8)]
pub type NodeAuthorization = pallet_node_authorization;
}


Thank you so much, this one worked and allowed my code to be compiled.

Here is the construct_runtime! macro:

https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/frame_support/macro.construct_runtime.html

Here is the #[runtime] attribute:

https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/frame_support/attr.runtime.html

Although there is a new macro, the old one remains available.
To use the new macro in your example, it should be:
#[runtime::pallet_index(x)]
pub type NodeAuthorization = pallet_node_authorization;

For more details, refer to: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/pull/1378.

Thank you for your response but I cannot see the full version of the construct_runtime! macro in the current lib.rs version of the substrate-node-template so that I can add that line for the pallet... I also tried the code that you have suggested but it didn't work as expected.

You can't mix the macros. Use frame_support::construct_runtime! or #[frame_support::runtime]. Please ink the code/log here if you get any error. Otherwise, I can't help with that.

Here in this codesandbox link I have my Cargo.toml and lib.rs files. There is also an errors.txt file in which I've listed the errors that I cannot understand, hence fix. I hope this can help.

The actual error is thrown by pallet_node_authorization during runtime construction. Please comment out all pallet_node_authorization code and see if the  node can be compiled.

Yes, the node can be compiled without the pallet_node_authorization codes. Is there any means for me to complete the tutorial even if the pallet is outdated?

You should check it yourself or submit another question. I believe this one is resolved; otherwise, the thread will become too lengthy.
